# If conditions in Factory Laravel

Tags: laravel, factory

I created a factory file in order to create fake elements to test my web system. And I want to know if there is a way to make a if condition to create another element based on the value of the element created previously.

It works perfectly with simple models, but with the ones that requires relations beetween the elements, I couldnt find a way to do it.

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\ItemDoEstoque::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'origem' => $faker->randomElement(['Fabrication','Raw','Resale','Cleaning','Others']),
        'quantity' => rand(100,999),
        'batch' => $faker->ean13,
        'date_fabrication' => $faker->date($format = 'Y-m-d', $max = 'now'),
        'date_validate' => $faker->date($format = 'Y-m-d', $max = 'now'),
        'stock_id' => function () {
          return App\Stock::inRandomOrder()->first()->id;
        },
        'product_sell_id' => function () {
          return App\ProductSell::inRandomOrder()->first()->id;
        },
        'product_buy_id' => function () {
          return App\ProductBuy::inRandomOrder()->first()->id;
        },
        'supplier_id' => function () {
          return App\Supplier::inRandomOrder()->first()->id;
        },
        'buyer_id' => function () {
          return App\Buy::inRandomOrder()->first()->id;
        },
        'reservation_id' => function () {
          return App\Fabrication::inRandomOrder()->first()->id;
        },
    ];
});
```

What I expect is that:
if origem = Fabrication, then batch, product_sell_id, quantity and date_fabrication wont be null, but the rest of them must be.
if origem = Raw, then:

```
'origem' => Raw,
'quantity' => NOT NULL,
'batch' => NULL,
'date_fabrication' => NULL,
'date_validate' => NOT NULL,
'stock_id' => NOT NULL,
'product_sell_id' => NULL,
'product_buy_id' => NOT NULL,
'supplier_id' => NOT NULL},
'buyer_id' => NULL,
'reservation_id' => NOT NULL
```

if origem = Fabrication, then:

```
'origem' => Fabrication,
'quantity' => NOT NULL,
'batch' => NOT NULL,
'date_fabrication' => NOT NULL,
'date_validate' => NOT NULL AND BIGGER THAN date_fabrication,
'stock_id' => NOT NULL,
'product_sell_id' => NOT NULL,
'product_buy_id' => NULL,
'supplier_id' => NULL},
'buyer_id' => NOT NULL,
'reservation_id' => NULL
```

and etc.

So please anyone know how to make this conditions like:
if  'origem' == Raw, then 'batch','date_fabrication','product_sell_id' and 'buyer_id' == null, and the rest get $faker->whatever type they are.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate some data out of returned array, and conditionaly set another fields.

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\ItemDoEstoque::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $orgiem = $faker->randomElement(['Fabrication','Raw','Resale','Cleaning','Others']);

    return [
        'origem' => $orgiem ,
        'quantity' => rand(100,999),
        'batch' => $orgiem == 'Fabrication' ? null : $faker->ean13,
        ...            
    ];
});
```